# Как реализовать кастомный таббар?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, uitabbar

Недавно занялся разработкой под iOS. В связи с этим делаю небольшое приложение, для которого подргуа нарисовала дизайн. По этому дизайну нижний таббар имеет специфичный вид (фото прилагаю). На нем мы видим две иконки слева и справа - переключение между вьюхами и по центру есть кнопка, которая отвечает за какое-то действие. Собственно вопрос, как возможно реализовать такую панель?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сделать через TabBarController - к нему можно задать фоном background, но этот background невозможно подогнать под определенный размер - картинка подставляется в оригинальном размере.
Второй способ - поместил небольшую view, в которую разместил на весь размер UIImageView и кнопки. Такой подход был уже немного лучше - удалось добиться корректного отображения на экранах iPhone 7/8, но из-за разных разрешений на iPhone 5 или X отображалось уже некорректно.

Еще есть догадка, возможно можно как-то отрисовать данный элемент ломанный (прямо отрисовать, потому что по факту это прямоугольная картинка с прозрачностью в центре, из-за которой не работают UI элементы (именно в этой части, когда я тапаю на UIImage как бы) (скролл картинок на заднем фоне, к примеру)

Всем зараннее спасиибо за любую обратную связь!

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать свой UIViewController класс вместо таббара. Нижний view отрисовать как вы хотите, а над ним сделать контейнер для view controller'ов

Comment: Спасибо! Я как раз и написал, что во втором варианте я попробовал создать обычный UIViewController и снизу отобразить этот "тулбар". Но столкнулся с ошибками, такими как на разных устройствах разная ширина и высота этого тулбара. И в принципе, не до конца понимаю насколько это правильно - делать редирект между UIViewController'ами обычными баттонами

Comment: Для начала, в данном дизайне не учтено, что на всех X нельзя перекрывать Home зону. По отрисовке - используйте UIBezierPath.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Можно немного поподробнее про отрисовку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `UIView` есть метод `draw(_:)`, в котором мы можем отрисовать все что угодно при желании. Для этого необходимо его переопределить и вот что примерно по вашему вопросу прописать:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    pathColor.setFill()
    // MARK: - значения взяты "на глаз" и необходимо заменить на значения по дизайну
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
    path.move(to: startPoint)
    let sideCurveEnd = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 30)
    let sideCurveCP = CGPoint(x: startPoint.x, y: sideCurveEnd.y)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: sideCurveEnd, controlPoint: sideCurveCP) 
    let centerArcBegin = CGPoint(x: rect.midX - 45, y: sideCurveEnd.y)
    path.addLine(to: centerArcBegin)
    let centerFirstArcEnd = CGPoint(x: centerArcBegin.x + 15, y: centerArcBegin.y + 10)
    let centerFirstArcCP = CGPoint(x: centerFirstArcEnd.x - 5, y: centerArcBegin.y)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: centerFirstArcEnd, controlPoint: centerFirstArcCP)
    let centerSecondArcEnd = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: centerFirstArcEnd.y + 20)
    let centerSecondArcCP = CGPoint(x: centerFirstArcEnd.x + 5, y: centerFirstArcEnd.y + 10)
    let centerSecondArcCP2 = CGPoint(x: centerFirstArcEnd.x + 15, y: centerSecondArcEnd.y)
    path.addCurve(to: centerSecondArcEnd, controlPoint1: centerSecondArcCP, controlPoint2: centerSecondArcCP2)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.close()
    path.fill()
    // MARK: - отражаем часть, так как симметрична, дабы не расписывать.
    let mirrorPath = path
    mirrorPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
    mirrorPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: rect.width, y: 0))
    mirrorPath.fill()
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на пример: [GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/UIBezierPathExample)

Comment: Отличный ответ. Вы очень помогли мне! Правда, я бы хотел узнать - есть ли возможность отключить тень с нижней стороны этой фигуры!

Comment: @denshest можете задать путь для тени, можете добавить еще одну вьюшку, которая перекроет тень.